# How can I avoid the runaway greenhouse effect on a planet with 2x Earth masses and a dense thick atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, gravity, greenhouse-effect

I've been working on a spec bio project with a planet which is 2x Earth masses with a dense atmosphere. However, I have one big issue : how do I avoid making a runaway greenhouse effect? Like the planet ending up like venus or somehow worse. I just want it to be a kind of warm jungle type of planet, so how do I avoid a runaway greenhouse effect?

Comment: Why do you feel obligated to include greenhouse gases in your atmosphere? Or why don't you just put your planet further? Or make your star less bright? Also, the "xenobiology" tag has nothing to do with your question, since your question does not pertain to biology

Comment: I've edited a bit your question to make it easier to read (be careful of punctuation!). Normally I've changed only its shape, not its content; but if you feel like I've changed too much, feel free to add your own improvements .

Comment: @JerryRobinson [That's just how the site works](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/editing)  (and by extent all wikis, including Wikipedia). Please understand that if you don't care about the quality of your work -including the question to make said world better!-, why would others care about it, either ? This could -in part- explains the [downvote](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) you received. My comment was just to make sure I haven't unwillingly distorted the core meaning of your query.

Comment: @JerryRobinson If you felt I was threatening or insulting, I'm sorry, that wasn't my intention . I just wished to help you understand the mindset and cogs of this website ⚙️. I hope knowing this will ease your mind, even if only by a little. Be careful though : Even if you felt hurt -intentionally or unintentionally-, this [doesn't give you the right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_wrongs_don%27t_make_a_right) to raise yourself the voice in return. Or raising the word, here ^^.

Comment: Okay sorry didnt mean to hurt any feelings if i did

Answer (score 1):

Given the extent of temperate and tropical woodland and rainforest biomes on Earth, it seems like you could already class it as a "jungle" world, especially at points in the past when it was warmer and things like [polar rainforests existed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_forests_of_the_Cretaceous). No need for a radically different atmosphere to ours... just a bit more CO<sub>2</sub> and a slight change in insolation. Even in the Cretaceous super-greenhouse period there were deserts and icecaps, because planets are big and complex and trying to dress them up with a single biome all-over is pretty impractical.

Thick atmospheres are fine so long as the world in question is far enough from its parent star so that the atmosphere keeps it warm and hospitable without boiling it. Atmospheric simulation is exceedingly complex, but honestly you can just avoid giving too much detail in your setting and handwave in the world that you want. If you want a single-biome jungle world, then you've already left the territory of hard-scifi, so you should absolutely handwave in whatever you want that feels good.

Comment: The planet isnt jungle all over there are tundra's and desert's and other biomes but it is mostly jungle

Answer (score 0):

I can say you, what I've found in my simularor database, getting such planet like Venus is extremely hard - in terms of infrared emissivity of 0.012 - and solved by my meticulously calculated physical formulae, from 20k created bodies only 9 went below 0.1 of this parameter. This means, that high temperatures are on their surfaces - well over 100 deg. But those planets are small - the biggest is 0.9 EM, other rather super-martians or smaller.

The closest to your conditions I see is a planet nr 21. It's 2.1 EM, 0.14 emissivity, venus-like albedo and temperature over 1000 deg. Why is that? Just because it's orbiting W-I type star. Even don't know what the hell is it... But it's not a "normal" star, of types we are familiar with for life creation. So why is Venus like that?? In my opinion, Venus and my planet nr 3 orbiting normal sun-like star, went under some abnormal conditions during its life-span creation, namely catastrophic ones. Fairly catastrophic. I hope in my optimistic world they are rarer than frequent.

So to get a world of 2x EM planet and have warm jungle with normal IR emissivity you have many choices. For example, I random choose something:

Planet of 2.01 EM, orbiting G0V star at 1.39 AU, 1.425 Eg, avg. temperature of 19 deg, earth-like IRE - 0.69 (quite higher than calculated 0.615 for Earth, but big jungle will produce a bit more CO2 in the future), the atmosphere is 2.02 EA (is thick I guess) and supports Helium in upper layers, which is believed to be on Earth earlier, but the gravity is below a threshold to keep it constantly. Rarithräz - the generated name, whatever that means ;)

Enjoy :P

**EDIT**

I can give you one more example because just sorted planets for the real "junglistic" one and found a forest master which is covered with 75% of woods, 13.9% oceans but 2.7 billion people found it as a host despite quite thick atmosphere of 2.67 of earthian (880 mln sq kms of land is a lot of place to live there). It's almost 3x EM but sane year as Earth and density and same gravity as Rarithräz had before. Temperature of 24 degrees may remind of Carbon life hundreds million years ago, or maybe a bit later. Tilt 12.45 deg, dobe 24 hours flat. Star type G4V. Planet name: Tirus.

As you can see finding such planet by physical conditions is not that hard with optimistic assumptions for degrees of freedom.

Comment: There are several types of degrees when measuring temperatures. Which one is it here : Celsius, Farhenheit?

Comment: @Tortliena always use Celsius here. Sorry for ambiguity